# Times before 10 am should show leading 0 for hours

Tags: feature-request, timestamps

I had an upvote on an old question of mine that happened to be early in the morning Stack Overflow time (UTC), and I noticed that there's no leading zero.

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) specifies that all times shall have a leading zero (though *durations* may omit it).

So, [as part of conforming to the ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock), Stack Overflow should show leading zeros for hours before 10 am.

e.g.
[image: Screenshot illustrating missing leading zeros for time of day]

Comment: Odd that this has 09 upvotes.

Comment: SO time == UTC btw.

Comment: Oh please *no*. I hate leading zeros when dates and times appear in normal text, and I live in a 24-hour country. And your "most 24-hour time systems" thing needs a citation.

Comment: I agree with balpha. Adding leading zeros is something for sorting or aligning, e.g in tabular data.

Comment: The abscense of AM/PM suffix makes it clear it is in 24-hour format.

Comment: @balpha, it's part of the ISO 8601 standard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock

Comment: I'm going to give you (valueless) bonus points for even attempting to pull the ISO 8601 card on a datetime that reads "Apr 29 at 0:57" while linking to a Wikipedia article about 24-hour time that says that the zero is optional for hours.

Comment: @TimStone Huh, actually [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) **requires** padding zeroes.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ Yes, but that's largely unrelated to the "requirements" of 24-hour time itself (the bit about the leading zero being optional is in the 24-hour clock article).

Comment: @TimStone I don't know where you are going with this. `[hh] refers to a zero-padded hour between 00 and 24`. I pulled the standard and it actually mandates leading zeroes (section 3.6)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ It mandates them for ISO 8601 datetimes, which "Apr 29 at 0:57" is not.

Answer (score 11):

If we want to go with the ISO 8601 standard, then do it fully, not only for the time portion.
This would mean to write `2011-04-29 00:57` for your second example above.

If we leave the date as `Apr 29` (or `Apr 29 '11` for dates longer ago), then we don't have an ISO-formatted date anyways, so there is no point in the leading zero.

Comment: I'm assuming this answer is trying to point out that in this case, conforming to the standards might not be what we want to do?

Comment: I'm not really sure here. I would like the full ISO form of the date, but if we are going informal anyway ("Apr 29"), we can also stay without leading zeros.